# Android deep link web url with intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I am trying to launch 
https://whereismytrain.in/web/pnr/4353132432 page to launch my activity where I can use 4353132432 number as a variable.

I have declared the following in the manifest file.

```
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="whereismytrain.in"
                    android:pathPrefix="/web/pnr/(PNR)"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I use the following code in Activity to read it.

```
urlParamPnr = getArguments().getString("PNR", "");
```

But this code is not working?
Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: what makes you think this should work?

Answer (score 1):

The following code has solved my issue.

```
 Intent urlIntent = getIntent();
 if (urlIntent != null) {
     Uri value = urlIntent.getData();
     if (value != null) {
           List<String> params = value.getPathSegments();
           urlParamPnr = params.get(2); // "pnr"
     }
 }
```